# Problema con DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR en PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Estoy intentando hacer dos `selects` anidados, en el que cuando se cambie el valor del primero se cargue en el siguiente unos valores recogidos de la Base de Datos. Para ello estoy intentando hacerlo mediante [php](/questions/tagged/php) y [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax).

El código de los **selects** es el siguiente:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3">
                <p class="letraAzulOsucroN"><?php echo $gen_campus; ?>:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="span9">
                <select id="campus" name="campus" onchange="cargarEdificios(this);" >
                    <option value="-1"><?php echo $pccrear_elegir_campus; ?></option>
                    <?php 
                    foreach ($campus as $camp){
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $camp->id; ?>">
                                <?php echo $camp->nombre; ?></option>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div><br />

        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3">
                <p class="letraAzulOsucroN"><?php echo $gen_edificio; ?>:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="span9">                 
                <select id="edificios" name="edificios" >
                    <option value="-1"><?php echo $pccrear_elegir_edificio; ?></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div><br />
```

y la petición **ajax** es la siguiente:

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">

        function cargarEdificios (obj){

            var campus = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value; 
            var idioma = $('#selLang').val();

            var parametros = {"idCampus": campus, "idioma" : idioma};

            <?php
             $rutaObtencion = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ."UVControlAulasPC" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ."controlAulas". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ."Utiles". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ."obtenerEdificios.php";
            ?>

            $.ajax ({
                data:       parametros,
                url:        "<?php echo $rutaObtencion; ?>",
                type:       'post',
                beforeSend: function (){
                                // Lanzar el div de cargando...
                            },
                success:    function (response){
                                $("#edificios").html(response);
                            }
            });
        }

    </script>
```

Cuando lo estoy probando me sale el siguiente error por la consola del navegador de Chrome:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el que se puede ver que no encuentra el archivo porque la dirección que le mando al ajax desaparecen las barras.

¿Alguien me podría decir a que es debido esto?¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿por qué usar DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR? En este caso, al ser una petición de una URL siempre será con `/`. Si fuera que estuvieras intentando abrir un fichero, entonces podría haber diferencias entre Windows y UNIX/Linux pero no para una URL (y si no me equivoco, incluso en ese caso Windows funcionará con `/`)

Comment: Lo estoy utilizando para que fueran las rutas independientes del sistema operativo por el problema de rutas con \ ó / ya que no se aún donde va a ir la página

Comment: voy a probar a ponerlas fijas como me comentas @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro si que ha funcionado, era algo tan sencillo que me da vergüenza haber preguntado esto

Comment: Que no te dé vergüenza. Estas cosas pequeñas son las que más dolores de cabeza causan siempre

Comment: y tanto, me he tirado un buen rato buscando el origen del fallo

Comment: Ponlo como respuesta y acéptala o cierra la pregunta. Aunque mejor lo primero, porque podría servir de ayuda a alguien que se encuentre en la misma situación

Comment: En verdad es interesante.... he borrado antes mi comentario porque he hecho algunas pruebas antes y en teoría no te debería dar problemas (lo he probado localmente)... aunque `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` no esta hecho para eso...pero si podrías por ejemplo definir lo por tu mismo `define('URL_SEPARATOR', '/');`

Comment: Gracias @aldanux he tenido un error de concepto, creía que se podía utilizar también para las URLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias a la ayuda de @AlvaroMontoro y de @aldanux me he dado cuenta que estaba usando mal el `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` ya que lo que estoy haciendo es una petición de una URL por lo que deberá utilizarse la barra '/' , por lo que el código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
     function cargarEdificios (obj){

        var campus = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value; 
        var idioma = $('#selLang').val();

        var parametros = {"idCampus": campus, "idioma" : idioma};

        $.ajax ({
            data:       parametros,
            url:        '/UVControlAulasPC/controlAulas/Utiles/obtenerEdificios.php',
            type:       'post',
            beforeSend: function (){
                            // Lanzar el div de cargando...
                        },
            success:    function (response){
                            $("#edificios").html(response);
                        }
        });
    }

</script>
```

otra forma de solucionarlo sería definir una variable que contega el separador de URL de la siguiente forma:

```
define('URL_SEPARATOR', '/');
```

y utilizar en el código de la petición ajax:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
     function cargarEdificios (obj){

        var campus = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value; 
        var idioma = $('#selLang').val();

        var parametros = {"idCampus": campus, "idioma" : idioma};

        <?php
         $rutaObtencion = URL_SEPARATOR."UVControlAulasPC" . URL_SEPARATOR."controlAulas". URL_SEPARATOR."Utiles". URL_SEPARATOR."obtenerEdificios.php";
        ?>

        $.ajax ({
            data:       parametros,
            url:        "<?php echo $rutaObtencion; ?>",
            type:       'post',
            beforeSend: function (){
                            // Lanzar el div de cargando...
                        },
            success:    function (response){
                            $("#edificios").html(response);
                        }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Gracias por la ayuda!